# Drop sqlite3 trigger in xcode

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite, triggers

I want to Drop som trigger in my Database,I used that:
   const char *dropTrigger1 = "drop trigger delete_msg";
   sqlite3_exec(database, dropTrigger1, NULL, NULL, NULL)
but it returns 26
Many helps?
Thanks :D

Comment: Is `database` a valid database file? See http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html for sqlite return codes.

Comment: Yes, I try to Select database, its OK